# Private Nested class

Tags: c#, exception, nested

I was following a tutorial about nested classes
But for me, it gives an inconsistent accessibility exception

Why does this work for him ?

[Tutorial video](https://youtu.be/yIziVLngkXQ?t=90)

```
class Employee
    {
        private class Manager
        {

        }
        public Manager man = new Manager();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have `man` declared as `public` when `Manager` is declared `private`. A caller from the outside could see `man` but not `Manager`, so `man` would be of no use to him.

Either make `man` `private` or `Manager` `public`.

Comment: I want to make a class that can not be created outside the Man class. is this possible

Comment: Then you need a private constructor.

Comment: But how can I access the private constructor only from Employee? It gives me an inaccessible due to its protection level warning.

Comment: That's not possible. You might want to consider exposing an interface for `Manager` instead directly exposing `Manager`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2736896/1210053